# Can evolution occur at level 100?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have a level 74 *Braixen* which I have given the *Everstone* to prevent her from evolving. There are many reasons, including I kind of like the look of her current evolution better than her fully evolved form. However, I would like to know what will happen if I level Braixen up to level 100 without letting her evolve.

If I remove the Everstone will she forever stay a Braixen? Or will she try evolving into Delphox?

If she doesn't evolve, will there be a way for her to evolve later as there will be no more XP gained from battling?

I have never done this before I have always allowed my Pokemon to evolve eventually so I was wondering if someone has tried this or knows what will happen?

Comment: This question is specific to [tag:Pokemon-x-y]. A more general question, which includes the change in this mechanic for generation 8, has been [asked and answered here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362566/can-a-level-100-pok%c3%a9mon-evolve-in-any-pok%c3%a9mon-series-game/362567#362567).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a Pokemon is level 100, unevolved and evolves by level, it will remain unevolved forever. The evolution process is started by a new level obtained and there is no way to level down to level back up. So if you get it to level 100 without evolving it, it will remain that way. Only stone and trading evolution can occur at max level; happiness/etc evolutions also can't occur since they also trigger on level up.